# Javascript HideRows (Google Sheet Script Editor)

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am trying to hide all the row of a specific Sheet in a Google speadsheet (the spreasheet contains others sheets). The rows to be hidden are the one with an ID between two intergers given by a two `prompt` commands (first_r  and last_r).

When I click on the button `hide`, I get the two prompt window, but then a "Finished script" but the row aren't hidden.
Here is my code

```
function hide(){
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var first_r_str = ui.prompt('First row to hide');
var last_r_str = ui.prompt("Last row to hide");
 var first_r = parseInt(first_r_str);
 var last_r = parseInt(last_r_str);   

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('MYSheet');

for (i = first_r; i <= last_r; i++){
sheet.hideRows(i); 
}

function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Hide Rows', 'hide')
      .addToUi();
}
```

My code is in the script editor(from the spreadsheet top menu, select tools and then script editor)

Comment: [Ui doesn't seem to have a hideRows method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui) You want to get the [sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) and hide the rows.

Comment: Thanks @RobinGertenbach! I have tried (and edited the code above) with "sheet.hideRows(i); ", still getting the same result : the rows aren't hidden. But if I add just before the `for` loop  these comamnds `sheet.hideRows(50);  
sheet.hideRows(51);  
sheet.hideRows(52);  `
 then those 3 rows get hidden.  So something seems to be wrong in my `for` loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code works perfectly fine, you missed to get the text value properly and can use the range.

Source [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/)

```
function hide(){
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

var startRow = ui.prompt('enter first').getResponseText();
var endRow = ui.prompt('enter last').getResponseText();
var range = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, endRow);
ss.hideRow(range);

}

function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Hide Rows', 'hide')
      .addToUi();
}
```

Comment: That's misleading, I think the main issue was that Op was not using getResponseText. [hideRows(rowIndex)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hideRows(Integer)) does exist.

Comment: For some reason I have to use this otherwise the endRow is the value I enter for endRow+ the startRow (If I enter 5 and 90, then the row 5 to 95 will be hidden). This fix it :`var range = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, endRow-startRow+1);`

Comment: @Enora the reason is [well documented](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hiderowsrowindex-numrows)! If you pass two values, the second value is the number of rows you wish to hide. You are (were?) treating this function as if the second value you are passing is the row to hide up until - which is a common misconception and the reason not-a-few people get a **range is out of bounds** error

Answer (score 1):

As MGA shows in his example the main problem is that you did not extract the text from the answer.

Since you have a consecutive range you should do one call to `hideRows` rather than looping, that is more efficient.

```
function hide(){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var first_r_str = ui.prompt('First row to hide').getResponseText();
  var last_r_str = ui.prompt("Last row to hide").getResponseText();
  var first_r = parseInt(first_r_str);
  var last_r = parseInt(last_r_str);   

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  sheet.hideRows(first_r, last_r - first_r + 1); 
}
```

Comment: Rather as new answer i guess you could have requested for edit or put a comment, as it doesn't add any value.